# Hangman program

Tags: python, python-2.7

Alright, so I'm working on a final project for my CSCI course and I decided to go with a hangman program because it's a fairly simple game to implement. I have everything working exactly how it's supposed to except the only problem I am getting is with some of my print statements. Code is below:

```
import random
import os

HANGMANPICS = ['''

        +---+
        |   |
            |
            |
            |
            |
            |
      =========== ''','''
        +---+
        |   |
        O   |
            |
            |
            |
            |
      =========== ''','''
        +---+
        |   |
        O   |
        |   |
            |
            |
            |
      =========== ''','''
        +---+
        |   |
        O   |
       /|   |
            |
            |
            |
      =========== ''','''
        +---+
        |   |
        O   |
       /|\  |
            |
            |
            |
      =========== ''','''
        +---+
        |   |
        O   |
       /|\  |
       /    |
            |
            |
      =========== ''','''
        +---+
        |   |
        O   |
       /|\  |
       / \  |
            |
            |
      =========== ''']

ANIMALS = '''cat dog fish whale otter spider snake bird dolphin tiger mouse 
      rabbit bear lion'''
CITIES = '''indianapolis chicago orlando miami denver columbus memphis oakland
     seatlle phoenix dallas detroit baltimore cincinatti'''
COUNTRIES = '''india china america japan egypt greece mexico italy canada 
        australia france brazil germany korea'''

def Countries():
    print 'Guess the name of this country'
    return COUNTRIES

def Cities():
    print 'Guess the name of this city'
    return CITIES

def Animals():
    print 'Guess the name of this animal'
    return ANIMALS

def Random():
    print 'Guess the name of this randomly chosen country, city, or animal'
    return COUNTRIES + CITIES + ANIMALS

def Welcome():
    print ('Select a category:')
    print ('1: Countries')
    print ('2: Cities')
    print ('3: Animals')
    print ('4: Random')

    choice = {"1": Countries, "2": Cities, "3": Animals, "4": Random}
    choose = raw_input()
    return choice.get(choose, Random)().split()


def getRandomword(wordlist):
    wordindex = random.randint(0, len(wordlist)-1)
    return wordlist[wordindex]

def Display(HANGMANPICS,MISSEDLETTERS,CORRECTLETTERS,SECRETWORD):
    os.system('cls')
    print(HANGMANPICS[len(MISSEDLETTERS)])
    print

    print 'Missed letters:',
    for letter in MISSEDLETTERS:
        print letter,
    print

    blanks = '_' * len(SECRETWORD)

    for i in range(len(SECRETWORD)):
        if SECRETWORD[i] in CORRECTLETTERS:
            blanks = blanks[:i] + SECRETWORD[i] + blanks[i+1:]

    for letter in blanks:
        print letter
    print

def getGuess(alreadyguessed):
    while True:
        print 'Guess a letter'
        guess = raw_input()
        guess = guess.lower()
        if len(guess) != 1:
            print 'Please enter single letters'
        elif guess in alreadyguessed:
            print 'This letter has already been guessed, please guess again'
        elif guess not in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
            print 'You did not guess a letter, please guess a letter'
        else:
            return guess

def playAgain():
    print ('Do you wanna play again? (Yes or No)')
    return raw_input().lower().startswith('y')

print ('Welcome to Hangman! By Aaron Taylor')
print (HANGMANPICS[6])
words = Welcome()
MISSEDLETTERS = ''
CORRECTLETTERS = ''
SECRETWORD = getRandomword(words)

done = False

while True:
    Display(HANGMANPICS,MISSEDLETTERS,CORRECTLETTERS,SECRETWORD)
    guess = getGuess(MISSEDLETTERS + CORRECTLETTERS)

    if guess in SECRETWORD:
        CORRECTLETTERS = CORRECTLETTERS + guess
        found = True
        for i in range(len(SECRETWORD)):
            if SECRETWORD[i] not in CORRECTLETTERS:
                found = False
                break

        if found:
             print('You won the game!')
             print('The correct word was ---->' + SECRETWORD.upper())
             done = True

    else:
        MISSEDLETTERS = MISSEDLETTERS + guess
        if len(MISSEDLETTERS) == len(HANGMANPICS)-1:
            Display(HANGMANPICS,MISSEDLETTERS,CORRECTLETTERS,SECRETWORD)
            print('You did not guess the word correctly. The word was : ' + SECRETWORD)
            done = True

    if done:
        if playAgain():
            os.system('cls')
            words = Welcome()
            MISSEDLETTERS = ''
            CORRECTLETTERS = ''
            done = False
            SECRETWORD = getRandomword(words)
        else:
            break
```

I am looking to get the print statements in Countries, Cities, Animals, and Random to print on the actual game screen after the choice is made, but I'm not having any luck, it works if I take out the os.system('cls') from both spots but they help make the program look nicer, which would also be a plus. Any suggestions to help get these print statements to work would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Actual game screen ? Whereabouts?

Comment: Just above the hangman graphic itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you call `os.system('cls')` after the print statements in Cities(), Countries() etc. get called.  Let's look at your code structure here:

```
print ('Welcome to Hangman! By Aaron Taylor')
print (HANGMANPICS[6])
words = Welcome()
MISSEDLETTERS = ''
CORRECTLETTERS = ''
SECRETWORD = getRandomword(words)

done = False

while True:
    Display(HANGMANPICS,MISSEDLETTERS,CORRECTLETTERS,SECRETWORD)
```

When `Welcome()` exists, it calls the appropriate function, say `Cities()`

```
def Cities():
    print 'Guess the name of this city'
    return CITIES
```

This print statement get called and printed, but almost immediately execution will have flowed into your `while True` loop, which calls `Display()` which immediately calls `os.system('cls')`, erasing the print made inside `Cities()`.  Does that make sense?

I think the best way to do this would be to store their choice inside a variable and have `Display()` print the right message after clearing the screen. However, this would involve a slight restructuring of your code.  A hackish way to do this is to derive their choice based on the current return value of Welcome.  Here's my hack to your code that I think does what you want:

```
def Display(HANGMANPICS,MISSEDLETTERS,CORRECTLETTERS,SECRETWORD, CHOICE):
    os.system('cls')
    CHOICE()
    print(HANGMANPICS[len(MISSEDLETTERS)])
    print

    print 'Missed letters:',
    for letter in MISSEDLETTERS:
        print letter,
    print

    blanks = '_' * len(SECRETWORD)

    for i in range(len(SECRETWORD)):
        if SECRETWORD[i] in CORRECTLETTERS:
            blanks = blanks[:i] + SECRETWORD[i] + blanks[i+1:]

    for letter in blanks:
        print letter
    print

def getGuess(alreadyguessed):
    while True:
        print 'Guess a letter'
        guess = raw_input()
        guess = guess.lower()
        if len(guess) != 1:
            print 'Please enter single letters'
        elif guess in alreadyguessed:
            print 'This letter has already been guessed, please guess again'
        elif guess not in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
            print 'You did not guess a letter, please guess a letter'
        else:
            return guess

def playAgain():
    print ('Do you wanna play again? (Yes or No)')
    return raw_input().lower().startswith('y')

print ('Welcome to Hangman! By Aaron Taylor')
print (HANGMANPICS[6])
words = Welcome()
if words == ANIMALS:
    CHOICE = Animals
elif words == CITIES:
    CHOICE = Cities
elif words == COUNTRIES:
    CHOICE = Countries
else:
    CHOICE = Random

MISSEDLETTERS = ''
CORRECTLETTERS = ''
SECRETWORD = getRandomword(words)

done = False

while True:
    Display(HANGMANPICS,MISSEDLETTERS,CORRECTLETTERS,SECRETWORD,CHOICE)
    guess = getGuess(MISSEDLETTERS + CORRECTLETTERS)
```

Comment: I actually just made it harder than it was, all I needed was 'if SECRETWORD in COUNTRIES:' and then the print statement, thanks for the help though!

Comment: Hmmm, but then if they choose random wont the print statement give away what the category is?

Comment: Yah, I haven't really figured out a way to deal with that yet but for now it's at least doing what I wanted it to do, now I'm just having trouble implementing an option to quit without actually playing the game

Answer (score 0):

Try calling sys.stdout.flush() after the print statements.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities:

1)  libcurses-like cursor placement.  You can place the cursor anywhere on the (text) screen and print out text characters.  I don't know more than that off the top of my head - you'll have to look it up and hope for python bindings to libcurses.  ("urwid" might be useful here)

2)  the cheater way, can be used if you only need to change the last line of what you printed.  Use \r (carriage return) in your output, the cursor will go to the beginning of the line and overwrite what was there.